# В очереди проверок не переведена информация о "висячей" правке

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

Если в очереди проверок попадается вопрос, у которого висит еще не подтвержденное исправление, то в окошке с действиями появляется информация об этом. Сейчас она не переведена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17006
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17007
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17004

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.12.3.40888